# How do I determine programmatically if ehcache is running?

Tags: ehcache

I have a large java application that is configured to use JPA and Hibernate.  It is also supposedly configured to use ehcaching for both entity and query caching.  However, I have sql logging turned on and no entities are being cached.  All of the entity queries are happening on every request.

How can I determine at runtime if it is even running ehcache and whether it thinks an entity should be cacheable?

I didn't write this app so I'm stuck a bit here.

It uses declarations for the caching on the classes.

It is correctly using all the other declarations for Hibernate to perform the read/write operations.

Comment: EhCache doesn't "run", it's a library. What are you asking?

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```java
List<CacheManager> tempManagers = CacheManager.ALL_CACHE_MANAGERS;
System.out.println("# of CMs : " + tempManagers.size());
for (CacheManager tempCM : tempManagers) {
        System.out.println("Got: " + tempCM.getName());
        String[] cacheNames = tempCM.getCacheNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < cacheNames.length; i++) {
            String cacheName = cacheNames[i];
            System.out.println(cacheName+" - "+ tempCM.getEhcache(cacheName).getStatistics().toString());
        }
}
```

Comment: It prints Got: __DEFAULT__ and "cachename" - net.sf.ehcache.statistics.StatisticsGaterwat@1y6788898 

Why the cachemanager name is default? is it alright?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer - a debugger.

Put a breakpoint where you load an entity and follow it down the stack. See if it ever even attempts to get the object from EHCache. Also, check to see if it tries to put it in the cache after it fetches it from the DB.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this since I haven't downloaded it, etc...  It seems I'm using version 3.3.1 of ehcache.  However, I haven't been able to find the source code.  So you don't think there is a way to setup some kind of logging so that I know it even loaded and configured ehcache?

Comment: @Andrew - You don't need the EHCache source to see if it shows up in a stack in the debugger. You just need a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this in that way:

```
    public boolean areCachesDefined() {
        return this.cacheManagers.stream()
                .anyMatch(cacheManager -> cacheManager.getCacheNames().iterator().hasNext());
    }
```

where `cacheManagers` is a collection with cache handlers per cache type (for example `ehcache`)

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @mglauche is pretty good. Additionally during startup you can search if your logs are printing following :

```
o.s.c.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoyBean : Initializing EhCache CacheManager
```